# I am trying to find a "simple" way to store images (and data about them) using CakePHP and MySQL.This code has got me a bit confused

Tags: mysql, image, cakephp

I went through this article to make a file uploading site with Cakephp,
http://www.tuxradar.com/content/cakephp-tutorial-build-file-sharing-application

I suppose the relevant code to this question is this, a download and an upload function,

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Upload->create();
        if ($this->uploadFile() && $this->Upload->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The upload could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Upload->User->find('list');
    $users = $this->Upload->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'users'));
}

function uploadFile() {
    $file = $this->data['Upload']['file'];
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $id = String::uuid();
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'uploads'.DS.$id)) {
            $this->data['Upload']['id'] = $id;
            $this->data['Upload']['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $this->data['Upload']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
            $this->data['Upload']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function download($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Upload->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('UploadsUser')));
    $upload = $this->Upload->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Upload.id' => $id,
            'OR' => array(
                'UploadsUser.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                'Upload.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
            ),
        )
    ));
    if (!$upload) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->view = 'media';
    $filename = $upload['Upload']['filename'];
    $this->set(array(
        'id' => $upload['Upload']['id'],
        'name' => substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')),
        'extension' => substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1),
        'path' => APP.'uploads'.DS,
        'download' => true,
    ));
}
```

I am not quite sure what all that code is doing actually, but I am trying to make a page so I can display one of the images instead of downloading them. If make this statement,

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/uploads/download/'.$upload['Upload']['id']);?>
```

My webpage displays my image but I don't actually have a download folder, I added that extension because it appears that the download function adds it for some reason. If someone could explain what is happening there, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new controller method to view your images individually, something like this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Upload->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid upload'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Upload.' . $this->Upload->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('upload', $this->Upload->find('first', $options));
}
```

And then display the image in your /View/Uploads/view.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/uploads/download/'.$upload['Upload']['id']);?>
```